# Java dynamic Tree for mini-max algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, minimax

i am facing problem with implementation of tree used for mini-max algorithm for my AI module.

The tree I need to write will have 4 levels: root(0) - AI move(1) - player move(2) and AI move(3). Every level will contain *n* of children and will have fields like(Board state, field rate and coordinates to move). With my calculations on the third level of tree possible number of children would be about 25.000. How should I implement this?

At the moment I've implemented 3 different `ArrayList`s of Objects, each list for specific level:

- `firstDepthList` - contains Objects with possible board state, field rate and coordinates to move);
- `secondDepthList` contains Objects with possible board state(for every element from `firstDepthList`), field rate and coordinates to move; and
- `thirdDepthList` which contains Objects like above for every
  element from `secondDepthList`. Of course I've linked lists together for
  board and moves continuity.

Or maybe you would recommend better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Mini-max algorithm needs only one value: max (or minimum, depends on level number). You don't have to store all tree.

It can be implemented as recursive function. And no creating many states, only one boardState using (for example, chess figure move from A to B may be reverted)

```
double getRating(BoardState state, int currentPlayer, int depth){
     //current player has to be 1 or -1
     if (depth <= 0){
         return state.positionRating();
     }
     double bestRating = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
     for(Move m: state.possibleMoves(currentPlayer)){
         state.apply(m); // modify state
         double rating = currentPlayer * getRating(state, -currentPlayer, depth-1); 
         // player 1 wants to have biggest number, player -1: lowest
         bestRating = Math.max(bestRating, rating);
         state.revert(m) // restore state
     }
return bestState*currentPlayer;
}
```